# How to make mysql query fast while searchs with like

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have three table and I have to search them with a **like** match. The query runs over 10,000 records. It works fine but take 4 seconds to give results. What can I do to improve the speed and take it down to 1 second?

```
profile_category_table
----------------------
restaurant
sea food restaurant

profile_keywords_table
----------------------
rest
restroom
r.s.t

company_profile_table
---------------------
maha restaurants
indian restaurants
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT name
FROM (
        (SELECT PC_name AS name
         FROM profile_category_table
         WHERE PC_status=1
           AND PC_parentid!=0
           AND (regex_replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]','',remove_specialCharacter(PC_name)) LIKE '%rest%')
         GROUP BY PC_name)
      UNION
        (SELECT PROFKEY_name AS name
         FROM profile_keywords_table
         WHERE PROFKEY_status=1
           AND (regex_replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]','',remove_specialCharacter(PROFKEY_name)) LIKE '%rest%')
         GROUP BY PROFKEY_name)
      UNION
        (SELECT COM_name AS name
         FROM company_profile_table
         WHERE COM_status=1
           AND (regex_replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]','',remove_specialCharacter(COM_name)) LIKE '%rest%')
         GROUP BY COM_name))a
ORDER BY IF(name LIKE '%rest%',1,0) DESC LIMIT 0, 2
```

And I add INDEX FOR THAT columns too.

if a user search with text rest in textbox..the auto suggestions results should be..

### results

```
restaurant
sea food restaurant
maha restaurants
indian restaurants
rest
restroom
r.s.t
```

i used regex_replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9-]','',remove_specialCharacter(COM_name) to remove special characters from the field value and to math with that keyword..

Comment: Minor point: You don't need to have the word `table` in the names of tables. It's just noise.

Comment: some company names with dot characters that y i need it.

Comment: in my table some company profile names has the dot characters. ex:p.l.a motors,l.k.s gold house. like that..

Comment: hey thanks guys..when i remove that regular expression function it works too fast thanks a lot to you for your support..

Comment: but even so, `r.s.t` shouldn't match: after you "sanitize" the value, it become 'rst' which simply does not match with 'rest'

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of thing you can consider:

The main killer of performance here is probably the `regex_replace() ... like '%FOO%'`.  Given that you are applying function on the columns, indices are not going to take effect, leaving you several full table scans.  Not to mention regex replace is going to be heavy weight.  For the sake of optimization, you may

1. Keep a separate column, which stored the "sanitized" data, for which you create indices on, and leaving your query like `where pc_name_sanitized like '%FOO%'`
2. I am not sure if it is available in MySql, but in a lot of DMBS, there is a feature called function-based index.  You can consider making use of it to index the regex replace function

However even after the above changes, you will find the performance is not very attractive.  In most case, using like with wildcard at the front is avoiding indices to be used.  If possible, try to do exact match, or have the beginning of string provided, e.g. `where pc_name_sanitized like 'FOO%'`

As mentioned by other users mentioned, using `UNION` is also a performance killer.  Try to use `UNION ALL` instead if possible.

Comment: My suggestions are still the same.  The only thing is probably you cannot avoid having wildcard at the start.  Every other suggestions are still valid.  Btw, is it possible for your application to make use of some other indexing engine like Lucene to do the "auto suggestion" feature? Handcrafting such kind of feature with SQL doesn't sounds right to me.

Comment: hey thanks  Adrian Shum ..when i remove that regular expression function it works too fast thanks a lot to you for your support..

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `union` in between all queries, you can remove the `group by` option in all queries and you select only column having "rest" in it. so remove the function `"IF(name LIKE '%rest%',1,0)"`in the order by clause.

Comment: hey thanks mani..when i remove that regular expression function it works too fast thanks a lot to you for your support..

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say don't filter on the query. Do that on whatever language you're programming in. Regex_replace is a heavy operation regardless of the environment and you're doing this several times on a query of 10,000 records with a union of who knows how many more.

Comment: hi adrian i updates my problems for what i what so please consider it once again..

Comment: hey thanks adrian..when i remove that regular expression function it works too fast thanks a lot to you..

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite it completely.
`UNION` statements are killing performance, and you're doing the `LIKE` on too many fields.
Moreover you're searching into a temporary table (`SELECT field FROM (...subquery...)`), so without any indexes, which is really slow (1/1 chance to go through full-table scan for each row).

Comment: hi amiot i updates my problems for what i what so please consider it once again..

Comment: hey thanks Amiot ..when i remove that regular expression function it works too fast thanks a lot to you for your support..